# How to hide web part from available web part list?

Tags: web-part

I have a solution that deploys 2 visual web parts & an EditorPart. I don't wan users to be able to see the EditorPart in the available web parts list. How do I hide/remove that 1 webpart from the list?

*EditorPart is a webpart that is used as a tool pane for other web parts.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove simply the EditorPart from the list of web parts that get deployed in the _catalogs/webpart (template id 113). You should find it as part of your solution package, written in a Elements.xml file.

Instantiation should be done anyway separately in order to connect the Editor to its Web part via the GetToolParts (which i assume you already have it working).